# Play framework route parameter authorization

Tags: java, playframework, authorization, playframework-2.3

I have REST api on my page and for authentication I use the Play session.

Problem is with authorization, I have tens of endpoints looking like this:

```
GET          /api/domains/:domainId/properties/:propertyId/reports
```

I could add and `if` statement on each controller method to check whether user has permissions to that **domain** or **property**, but can I handle it somehow globally?

I found this module, but it does not seem to handle **parameters**, just checks if user is in some group/role or not. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.2.1/secure

Comment: You don't mention what version of Play you are using

Comment: @Gus it is 2.3 as in tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using a custom RequestHandler. There you can extract parameters from the path and validate them. (In scala I could even modify the request route in order to avoid repeating these parameters in all routes, I don't know if you can do it in java too).
(See: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpRequestHandlers)

Comment: Works nicely. Had to upgrade to 2.4 for it, but hey, why not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Security.Authenticated annotation as detailed [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition#Annotating-controllers). For more specific permissions, I recommend [Deadbolt](http://deadbolt.ws/)

Comment: I see that enables me to use roles and groups, but how do I do authorization based on route parameters?

Comment: It doesn't. The way I have been doing is to handle it in each controller method. I suppose it's possible using custom action annotations (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition#Defining-custom-action-annotations), but I haven't tried it myself.